# How to redirect logs to /dev/null when app is running using pm2?

Tags: node.js, pm2

I start a nodejs app using pm2, the log out-file config setting is default.

Now, i find the log is too huge, so i need to redirect the log to `/dev/null` without restarting the process and without using `pm2 -logrotate`.

Is there any way around this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to restart the process if you want a fresh redirection. If restarting is okay, then it could be like:

```
pm2 'command' > /dev/null
```

If not, then you can possibly write a very basic shell script and schedule it via cron. It would just clean your logs (`pm2 flush`), or compress and dump (whichever you prefer).

Comment: Thank you so much!